# Is there a comprehensive list of n-declensed nouns?

Tags: noun, declension

Is there a complete list of German *n*-declensed nouns in any book or on the web? I found some lists, but they do not seem to be comprehensive enough.

Comment: I don’t think anybody would ever create a really comprehensive list … there’s a lot of work to it …

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the answer and editing, so I think you imply that one has to learn by using the language.

Comment: The machine-readable dictionary I compiled for the project that led to my thesis lists 246 such entries, from *Abkomme* to *Zoologe*. Would that be of use to you?

Comment: @KilianFoth It may be of use, and apart from n-declension there is the thing that some nouns get '-n' as a suffix when their case is dative.

Answer (score 4):

im [Buch](http://www.schubert-verlag.de/erkundungen_b2_blick.php?PHPSESSID=05db9693c738b51aaead749c8dc8b811), das ich benutze, gibt es die folgende Seite, für mich ist sie gut:

[image]

Comment: Danke schön, aber leider kann ich das Wort "der Gast" nicht gesehen. Ich denke, dass es n-dekliniert ist.

Comment: @Vesnog den Gast, dem Gast, des Gastes

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Maybe I misused the terminology, but it changes in dative form as my instructor said. You can check this link:

http://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g1384976-i99416878-Bronte_Province_of_Catania_Sicily.html

Comment: @Vesnog ..., die Gäste, die Gäste, den Gästen, der Gäste http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gast

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Is there any dictionary which shows that kind of declination in akkusative or dativ cases?

Comment: ugs. können die Wörter der Gruppen 2., 3. und 4. auch im AkkSg und DatSg ohne _+n_ bleiben, während viele aus 5. dazu tendieren, auch im NomSg ein _-n_ anzunehmen (und dann evtl. im GenSg ein zusätzlichs _+s_).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this website for looking up specific words: [LEO](http://dict.leo.org)

[image]